# Is monotonicity of $g$ necessary and sufficient for preserving critical points of $f$ in $g(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

Problem 1. I want to find the argminof $f(x)$.  Suppose solving $f'(x)=0$ is too difficult. Instead, solve Problem 2: optimize $g(f(x))$, 
(presumably by solving $g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)=0$?).

For what types of functions, $g$, is Argmin$(f(x)) = $Argmin$(g(f(x)))$?

I recall it is sufficient if $g()$ is monotonically increasing, but is it necessary?

This is not homework, it is a too-tired memory.

Comment: Presumably **not** by solving $g'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = 0$.  That is certainly no easier, and just might give you extraneous solutions where $g'(f(x))$ happens to be $0$ even though $g$ is  increasing at $f(x)$.  And, by the way, unless you are willing to change "min" to "max", it should be monotone **increasing**, not just monotone.

Comment: Yes, I assumed it would be easier by cancelling out f'(x), which seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y_1 < y_2$ with $g(y_1) > g(y_2)$, and the minimum value of $f$ is $y_1$ while $y_2$ is also in the range of $f$, then $g \circ f$ and $f$ can't attain
their minima in the same point.  So for $g$ to work for **all** $f$, you do need
$g$ to be monotone increasing.